# how to read value from table view cell in iphone without selecting any row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook

thanks in advance
 i want to read cell value from tableview but without selecting any cell.
let me explain first
in my table view each cell have some value when  tableview is drown fist time this all value is coming from database.
then later through didselectedRowAtIndexPath for example  i select first cell value and take it in label in another view and change it a when i click save button on new view then my new value is coming back in first view in table view cell correctly this all operation is correctly working.

but my problem is that after changing some cell value i want to read all the data that display on table view cell but without selecting any cell in didselectedRowAtIndexPath or any other method i read this cell value on my save button on this view  and after read this value i again save it in database

Answer (score 5):

Geez, I think if I were you I'd go the other direction. You surely have a data structure of some sort (an NSArray, quite likely) that you used to populate your tables with data in the first place, right? Why not just get it from there, rather than getting your mitts on the UITableViewCell and digging into its view hierarchy to find the label you want?

Comment: +1 Querying the datasource is the only way to implement this correctly. If the tableview has rows that are offscreen there is (or at least should be) no cell to ask for data.

Comment: thanks but sir i change my array value what i first display in table view and after changing  i want to read my cell value and again save it in database

Comment: Well don't. If you need it again, the array is the place to get it from.

Comment: for that what can i do where i place array

Comment: @yogesh -- You'd need to show us some code, or else we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The `didselectedRowAtIndexPath` method is just a means to tell you what point in your array to read data from.  You have to create an array of some sort to build the table from.  If you know you want to read data from the first cell, simply read it directly from the array populating your table.  Doing this at the end of viewDidLoad would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

if its a custom cell use

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

NSLog("%@", cell.property):

Answer (score 0):

You can get cell for only visible rows without clicking them as

```
NSArray *visibleRowsArr = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[visibleRowsArr objectAtIndex:0]];
```

and from this cell you can get values for a tag which you have to specify while creating a cell.

Comment: you can put this in action of your save btn

Comment: thanks after adding in t action of save button application will terminated automatically and it dnt show anything